# Sort Magento 2 Category Products by Stock Quantity

Tags: magento2

I have a small "Problem" with Magento 2. In my Shop are "In Stock" and "Out of Stock" Items/Products. I am trying to find a Solution to Show first the Items/Products that are "In Stock" and at the last position on page the Items/Product "Out of Stock".

I find one Solution in the WEB but I am not understand how to Set it Up to function on my shop.

Here is the [reference](https://meetanshi.com/blog/sort-magento-2-category-products-by-stock-quantity/)

Can somebody direct me in the right way, where I need to make this File, in which Folder?

Thank you in advanced

Comment: If you are a developer, then please  a create a custom module which must have `events.xml` and `StockLast.php``

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Crate a module with below files:

MyCompany_SortBy

> app/code/MyCompany/SortBy/Registration.php

```
<?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
   \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
   'MyCompany_SortBy',
   __DIR__
);
```

> app/code/MyCompany/SortBy/composer.json

```
{
    "name": "mycompany/module-sortby",
    "description": "MyCompany sortby",
    "require": {
        "php": "~5.6.5|7.0.2|7.0.4|~7.0.6",
        "magento/framework": "100.1.*",
        "magento/module-theme": "100.1.*"
    },
    "type": "magento2-module",
    "version": "1.0.8",
    "license": [
        "OSL-3.0",
        "AFL-3.0"
    ],
    "autoload": {
        "files": [ "registration.php" ],
        "psr-4": {
            "MyCompany\\SortBy\\": ""
        }
    }
}
```

> app/code/MyCompany/SortBy/etc/module.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="MyCompany_SortBy" setup_version="1.0.0"/>
</config>
```

> app/code/MyCompany/SortBy/etc/events.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="catalog_block_product_list_collection">
        <observer name="stockLast" instance="MyCompany\SortBy\Observer\StockLast" />
    </event>
</config>
```

> app/code/MyCompany/SortBy/Observer/StockLast.php

```
<?php

namespace MyCompany\SortBy\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface;
use Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;
use Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Toolbar as CoreToolbar;

class StockLast implements ObserverInterface
{
    protected $scopeConfig;
    protected $_storeManager;
    protected $coreToolbar;

    public function __construct(
        ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig,
        StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        CoreToolbar $toolbar
    )
    {
        $this->scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
        $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;
        $this->coreToolbar = $toolbar;
    }

    public function execute(Observer $observer)
    {
        $collection = $observer->getEvent()->getData('collection');
        try {
            $websiteId = 0;
            $stockId = 'stock_id';
            $collection->getSelect()->joinLeft(
                array('_inv' => $collection->getResource()->getTable('cataloginventory_stock_status')),
                "_inv.product_id = e.entity_id and _inv.website_id=$websiteId",
                array('stock_status')
            );
            $collection->addExpressionAttributeToSelect('in_stock', 'IFNULL(_inv.stock_status,0)', array());
            $collection->getSelect()->reset('order');
            $collection->getSelect()->order('in_stock DESC');
            //code for Filter Price Low to High or High to Low with stock filter.

            if ($this->coreToolbar->getCurrentOrder() == 'price') {
                $direction = $this->coreToolbar->getCurrentDirection();
                $collection->getSelect()->order("min_price $direction");
            }
        } catch (Exception $e) {
        }
        return $this;
    }
}
```

Run below commands once the files are created:

> php bin/magento s:up;
>
> php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy

Comment: Have you tried above solution?